# meta random redirect random X seconds

Tags: javascript, php, meta

meta random redirect with random seconds.

```
<?php

$offers = array(
"http://www.url1.com",
"http://www.url2.com",
"http://www.url3.com",
"http://www.url4.com"
);

$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
if($referer == "") {
    $url = $offers[rand(0, count($offers) - 1)];
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=$url'>";
}
else
{
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://www.firstpage.com'>"; 
} 
?>
```

i need some one to add the random seconds ..
thank you

Comment: How is this a question? Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to generate a random number

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=$url'>";
```

will be:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='".mt_rand(0,20).";url=$url'>";
```

to redirect between 0 and 20 seconds.

Comment: how can i remove the " $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
if($referer == "") {
" and else